# Add on condition with Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Is there a way I can do something like this with Lambda expressions?

```
responses.Add(sr).Where(v.Responses.TryGetValue(v.responseType, out sr));
```

I want to use lambda expressions or a ternary operator instead of a typical if expression.

NB:

`responses` is a `List<string>` type.

`v.Responses` is a `Dictionary` of `<enum ResponseType, string>`

`v` is some object

`sr` is a string.

Comment: When `sr` is a String you cannot add it to a `Dictionary<enum ResponseType, string>`.

Comment: sorry, edited the question now.

Comment: Can you describe in words what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @RaymondChen: I want to add dictionary string values to a string list from the dictionary list if the dictionary key exists.

Comment: @opatachibueze: lambda expressions/linq/extensions methods are really necessary? Couldn't you write a couple of simple `if`/`for` statements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is:

```
string sr;
if (v.Responses.TryGetValue(v.responseType, out sr))
    responses.Add(sr);
```

There is no way to ease the syntax and get the same performance.
But you could do:

```
responses.AddRange( v.Responses.Where( p => p.Key == v.responseType )
                               .Select( p => p.Value ) );
```

You may want to think about what the last one is doing, because it is kind of stupid...

EDIT: the reason why it is stupid is because the last expression translates into:

```
foreach(var pair in v.Responses)
{
    if (pair.Key == v.responseType)
        responses.Add(pair.Value);
}
```

So if your ResponseType enumeration had 6 million entries, the program would iterate over the entire set of keys to find the correct entry. In your case, since you already know the key, you should use `v.Responses[key]` as it is extremely fast (see in which cases dictionaries must be use).

Comment: I'd like to highlight your last sentence. Is very inefficient to iterate a whole dictionary when you can perform a O(1) access by key.

Comment: @digEmAll Will this be efficient if the dictionary can only have a maximum of about 4 keys?

Comment: @opatachibueze: obviously not, but it's still kinda *stupid* to call `AddRange` to add one value only. In particular if you can do it using 3 clear lines of code.

Comment: completely understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is not supposed to modify collections.

Couldn't you simply do something like this:

```
  string sr;
  if(v.Responses.TryGetValue(v.responseType, out sr))
     responses.Add(sr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this might do what you're looking for.

Based on  your example code, I'm assuming that your object "v" contains a field named "responseType" of type RepsonseType.

```
var responses = v.Responses
    .Where(r => r.Key == v.responseType)
    .Select(r => r.Value)
    .ToList();
```